# Drawing textures in raycasting engine

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm, raycasting

I am trying to make a raycasting engine in assembly and i have a problem.
drawing textures does not seem to work properly.

This is how it looks like:

[image: img]

in the for loops of finding collision with the wall , if collision was found I took the floating point part of the x or the y and used it to calculate where on the texture to draw.

I have tried debugging and I have found that the problem could be that the final texture x is the same few times but you can see in the pictures that it works almost fine when looking from the side so i don't think it's the problem.

The wanted result is just that the textures will be drawn correctly without those distortions.

I think the problem is somewhere in the code [here](http://pastebin.com/07vEJAn1):

```
mov ebx,WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2
sub ebx,eax
mov eax,height

mov screenypos,ebx

dec typeofwall

movss xmm0,floatingpoint
mulss xmm0,FP4(64.0f)

mov eax,typeofwall
cvtsi2ss xmm1,eax
mulss xmm1,FP4(64.0f)

addss xmm0,xmm1

movss tempvarr,xmm0
invoke FLOOR,tempvarr
cvtss2si eax, xmm0
mov finaltexturex,eax

;invoke 

BUILDRECT,screenpos,screenypos,linewidth,height,hdc,localbrush

invoke DrawImage,hdc,wolftextures,screenpos,screenypos,finaltexturex,0,linewidth,64,linewidth,height
```

Comment: We help fix code. We're not here to look at pictures of stuff.

Comment: Paste the code here.

Comment: Why floating point? use 16:16 fixed point, if this is in 32b mode, that's enough accuracy, and easier to write. By for example 1:16 being 1 tile at map you have still about ~256 texture resolution with high accuracy, maybe stretching it as far as 2048 would work ok... if you want higher texture resolution, but 256x256 map is enough, then 8:24 (1:24 = +tile) can be used. Wolf3D didn't need FP coprocessor. :D (and had only 8:8 fixed point math with only 32 (5b) texture res IIRC).

Comment: I have added the code where i calculate the last stuff of the drawing + the textures are 64x64

Comment: i use floating point to check like what part of the texture to draw. lets say for an example i hit a wall on x:4.36 and y=4 then 0.36 * texturewidth is the starting position of where i need to start drawing the texture from

Comment: Had a quick look on the code, but I don't get it at all, why is there even screen `y`, is this full raytracing? In 2.5D raycasting you don't care about screen y, until you know which wall was hit for particular pixel column, how far it is from projection plane, then you use that to calculate bottom/top of pixel column coordinates. ... The fixed point suggestion is not your problem anyway, there must be different problem, actually I would suspect the intersection calculation (is the `floatingpoint` that? I would suspect it).

Comment: about float (unrelated to your problem): yes, that's what fixed point math does too: for example you have vector (0.45, 0.2), so in 16:16 fixed point you go over tiles by (+29491, +13107) and (positionx/y>>16) is tile x/y, (positionx/y>>10)&63 is 0..63 texturex/y coordinate. (65536 being "1.0" in 16:16 fixed point math) so `mov eax,0x00048000` is "4.5" then. you can write in such system whole intersection calculations, etc.. using only nonFP instructions. (On 80286 CPU it made quite a difference, as almost nobody had 80287 with HW floating point :) ).

Comment: the "screenypos" is the top place of where to draw the line but is not the problem because when i replace the drawimage with drawing simple rectangles with colors the x ,y ,width,height of the rectangle are correct and it draws it completelyfine

Comment: I think your other axis data are leaking into the desired one (so you get `y` fractions instead of `x` and vice-versa) .. it happens probably only with walls almost parallel with projection plane. (actually.. if 45 degree walls are fine, then it may leak all the time, and 45 degree are "ok" by accident :D )

Comment: i have checked it's not the problem . When i switch in the loops from x%1 and y%1 to the other one it just looks worse and not even close to texture. I dont think that's the problem

Comment: So are you sure, the fractional positions from intersection for those parallel walls make sense? like 4.02, 4.07, 4.12,  ... for screen columns next to other? put the camera right in front of single wall and see, the intersection coordinates should be linear (if the projection plane is parallel perfectly = view angle orientation is perpendicular to the wall). If the intersection data are good, then you will easily fix that asm part too :), as it will be obvious what happens during calculation in debug).

Comment: Can't you simply make a rectangular centered screen-facing wall the size of the texture and debug the rendering? Set a breakpoint on the texture lookup and check the numbers. Rotate the wall pi/4 rads and repeat. Keep rotating until a full turn.

Comment: @Ped7g: 32-bit fixed-point is usually not worth using on modern CPUs with powerful FPUs.  It is good for 16b or 8b esp. with SIMD. This is one of those cases where 286 advice is useless.  On Intel Haswell for example, FP and integer SIMD multiplies have the same latency, and the same throughput.  (Actually, packed 32-bit integer multiply is twice as slow).  But for fixed point, you also need shifts.  See the perf links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), esp. Agner Fog's insn tables.  Integer add is lower latency than FP add, but still the same throughput (for SIMD).

Comment: @PeterCordes performance wise it's useless, but it's easier to read (for me ;) ).. and you have uniform accuracy for whole coordinate space. So you have a good point, but I still think in cases like this fixed point can be in the end better... probably depends a lot, what is more familiar to the coder, I never got that much comfortable with FP instructions, probably some performance trauma from youth.. ;) (throughput wise this will stall on texture memory anyway, there's almost zero calculation going on during texturing itself and that's 99% of thing to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print first for each column the "hit" coordinates, and which one would you use for texturing (keep in mind, that you have to use either map_x or map_y axis for texturing, depending on which grid line the ray intersected first with the wall and from which direction).

Now I got other idea... are you even using the byte map[16][16]; or something similar for walls definitions (Wolf3D 2.5D ray casting), or is this semi-polygon map system, calculating intersections with segments (DOOM 2.5D perspective BSP 2D-edge drawer (not ray casting at all in original DOOM!))?

If you are doing the Wolf3D raycaster, be aware you have to clean up your intersection formulas a lot, and decide wisely which part of calculation you do when, as bad order of calculation may quickly cumulate considerable amount of accuracy error, leading to quirks like "holes" in walls (when for single pixel column you miss the intersection with wall), etc.

With floating point numbers you are even more susceptible to unexpected accuracy problems, as the accuracy encoded in bits shifts fast by exponent (so around 0.0,0.0 coordinates you have quite better accuracy, than around 1e6,1e6 coordinates on map).

When done properly, it should look like "easy" stuff. I once made quick and dirty version in Pascal in one afternoon (as an example for a friend, who was trying to learn Pascal). But it's as easy to do it wrong (for example Bethesda's first Elder Scrolls "ARENA" had horrible intersection calculation, with walls y-position being jagged a lot). And usually the not-proper calculation has not only worse accuracy, but also almost always involves more calculation operations, so it's slower.

Use paper and pencil to draw it all down (map grid, projection plane, triangulate around with values you have, look how you can minimize setup phase per screen-column-x, as minimum amount of calculation = highest accuracy).

(the answer is quite general, because there's almost no code to check (the code posted looks OK to me)).

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer . Now i am trying to fix the "holes" in the walls :)